# jPlayer pausing

Tags: jquery, jplayer

i have a background music playing on all pages (jPlayer) and i need to pause it when another embeded video is clicked/played on post or page or sidebar though this code doesn't seem to work:

```
<script>
//pauses jplayer
var selectors = [
        "iframe[src^='http://player.vimeo.com']", 
        "iframe[src^='http://www.youtube.com']", 
        "iframe[src^='https://www.youtube.com']", 
        "iframe[src^='http://www.kickstarter.com']", 
        "object", 
        "embed"
      ];
  $selectors.click(function() {
  $.jPlayer.pause();
});
</script>
```

what can be wrong?
[mysite link](http://artur.nickandlarry.ru/video)

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: $selectors is not definedUnsafe `                                        `JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://artur.nickandlarry.ru/video from frame with URL http://www.youtube.com/embed/SpPmfnU05KU. Domains, protocols and ports must match.` and just doesn't pause. The url is [link](http://artur.nickandlarry.ru/video)[link]

Comment: how to solve? any suggestions

Comment: may be this an cross domain issue because these two urls are different.And in  error is says Domain must match.this might work but I think this can be an implementation issue.Try to play video from the same site e.g  youtube.com

Answer (score 1):

Change `$selectors` to `$(selectors)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
// By Chris Coyier & tweaked by Mathias Bynens
$(function() {
// Find all videos
var selectors = [
    "iframe[src^='http://player.vimeo.com']", 
    "iframe[src^='http://www.youtube.com']", 
    "iframe[src^='https://www.youtube.com']", 
    "iframe[src^='http://www.kickstarter.com']", 
    "object", 
    "embed"
  ];
    // The element that is fluid width
var $allVideos = $(this).find(selectors.join(','));
// Figure out and save aspect ratio for each video
$allVideos.each(function() {
var $this = $(this);
$(this).hover(function(){
        $("#bgaudio").jPlayer("pause");
    },function(){
        $("#bgaudio").jPlayer("play");
    });
});
});
```

"click" is complicated for different video providers - "hover" works in all browsers except chrome , any ideas?